# Slick 2 - Update columns in a table and return whole table object

Tags: sql, scala, slick

How would you update a few columns in a table table while returning the entire updated table when using slick?

Assuming `SomeTables` is some `TableQuery`, you would typically write a query like this if you want to, for example, add an item to the table (and returning the newly added item)

```
val returnedItem = SomeTables returning SomeTables += someTable
```

How would you do the same if you want to update an item and return the whole back the whole item, I suspect you would do something like this

```
val q = SomeTables.filter(_.id === id).map(x => (x.someColumn,x.anotherColumn)) returning SomeTables
val returnedItem = q.update((3,"test"))
```

The following code however does not work, and I can't see any documentation on how to do this

Note that I am aware you can just query the item beforehand, update it, and then use copy on the original object, however this requires a lot of boilerplate (and DB trips as well)

Comment: I don't understand whether you want to update an object and return it or you want to update an object and then have the `TableQuery` with the update you just did, if the second probably you only have to append `.run` to the query you are executing.

Comment: Assuming that I have a full projection from a `case class` to the columns of the table, I want to update a subset of those columns (i.e. the `.map(x => (x.someColumn,x.anotherColumn))` and return the whole updated object (returning `SomeTables`). So in the example above, SomeTables could have a default `*` projection which would have 5 colums, I am updating two of those columns (`someColumn` and `anotherColumn`), however I want to return the whole `table` (or object) which would contain 5 columns

Comment: From my beginner experience I don't see a way out except for update and then select the row, the `update` method you're invoking returns an `Int` (that is whether the update was successful or not). Sorry I couldn't help, hopefully somebody with more experience will answer.

Comment: What is the error you are seeing? Compile time or runtime? Not all DMBS support what you have in mind and will throw an exception. Try `returning SomeTables.map(_.yetAnotherColumn)` and `returning SomeTables.map(x=>x)`.

Answer (score 6):

This feature is not supported in Slick (v2 or v3-M1); although I don't see any specific reason prohibiting it's implementation, `UPDATE ... RETURNING` is not a standard SQL feature (for example, H2 does not support it: http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#update). I'll leave as an exercise to the reader to explore how one might safely and efficiently emulate the feature for RDBMSes lacking `UDPATE ... RETURNING`.

When you call "returning" on a `scala.slick.lifted.Query`, it gives you a [JdbcInsertInvokerComponent$ReturningInsertInvokerDef](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.1.0/api/#scala.slick.driver.JdbcInsertInvokerComponent$ReturningInsertInvokerDef). You'll find no `update` method, although there is an `insertOrUpdate` method; however, `insertOrUpdate` only returns the `returning` expression result if an insert occurs, `None` is returned for updates, so no help here.

From this we can conclude that if you want to use the `UPDATE ... RETURNING` SQL feature, you'll either need to use [StaticQuery](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.1.0/sql.html#query-statements) or roll your own patch to Slick. You can manually write your queries (and re-implement your table projections as GetResult / SetParameter serializers), or you can try this snippet of code:

```
package com.spingo.slick

import scala.slick.driver.JdbcDriver.simple.{queryToUpdateInvoker, Query}
import scala.slick.driver.JdbcDriver.{updateCompiler, queryCompiler, quoteIdentifier}
import scala.slick.jdbc.{ResultConverter, CompiledMapping, JdbcBackend, JdbcResultConverterDomain, GetResult, SetParameter, StaticQuery => Q}
import scala.slick.util.SQLBuilder
import slick.ast._

object UpdateReturning {
  implicit class UpdateReturningInvoker[E, U, C[_]](updateQuery: Query[E, U, C]) {
    def updateReturning[A, F](returningQuery: Query[A, F, C], v: U)(implicit session: JdbcBackend#Session): List[F] = {
      val ResultSetMapping(_,
        CompiledStatement(_, sres: SQLBuilder.Result, _),
        CompiledMapping(_updateConverter, _)) = updateCompiler.run(updateQuery.toNode).tree

      val returningNode = returningQuery.toNode
      val fieldNames = returningNode match {
        case Bind(_, _, Pure(Select(_, col), _)) =>
          List(col.name)
        case Bind(_, _, Pure(ProductNode(children), _)) =>
          children map { case Select(_, col) => col.name } toList
        case Bind(_, TableExpansion(_, _, TypeMapping(ProductNode(children), _, _)), Pure(Ref(_), _)) =>
          children map { case Select(_, col) => col.name } toList
      }

      implicit val pconv: SetParameter[U] = {
        val ResultSetMapping(_, compiled, CompiledMapping(_converter, _)) = updateCompiler.run(updateQuery.toNode).tree
        val converter = _converter.asInstanceOf[ResultConverter[JdbcResultConverterDomain, U]]
        SetParameter[U] { (value, params) =>
          converter.set(value, params.ps)
        }
      }

      implicit val rconv: GetResult[F] = {
        val ResultSetMapping(_, compiled, CompiledMapping(_converter, _)) = queryCompiler.run(returningNode).tree
        val converter = _converter.asInstanceOf[ResultConverter[JdbcResultConverterDomain, F]]
        GetResult[F] { p => converter.read(p.rs) }
      }

      val fieldsExp = fieldNames map (quoteIdentifier) mkString ", "
      val sql = sres.sql + s" RETURNING ${fieldsExp}"
      val unboundQuery = Q.query[U, F](sql)
      unboundQuery(v).list
    }
  }
}
```

I'm certain the above can be improved; I've written it based on my somewhat limited understanding of Slick internals, and it works for me and can leverage the projections / type-mappings you've already defined.

Usage:

```
import com.spingo.slick.UpdateReturning._
val tq = TableQuery[MyTable]
val st = tq filter(_.id === 1048003) map { e => (e.id, e.costDescription) }
st.updateReturning(tq map (identity), (1048003, Some("such cost")))
```

Comment: Thanks! It would be great if there is a updated version for Slick 3.0 :-)

Comment: Is there any difference concerning this in Slick 3?

Comment: We haven't updated to Slick 3 here yet; I'm sure the general approach will work but it's likely that APIs and data structures have changes somewhat.

Comment: I've updated the code by @TimHarper for Slick 3.0 in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30212785/slick-3-0-update-columns-in-a-table-and-return-whole-table-object/31545270#31545270. Thanks a lot, Tim!