# Slick update return the updated object

Tags: scala, slick

I'm trying to have a function return the updated object after the db runs an update method on the query right now, but I can't figure out how to successfully return the object. This is a function I wrote using examples I found, but I would like to extend q.update(cat) to return a Future[Cat].

```
def update(id: Long, cat: Cat): Future[Unit] = db.run {
  val q = for { c <- cats if c.id === id } yield c
  q.update(cat).map(_ => ())
}
```

Comment: You might want to look at [this question and its answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30212785/slick-3-0-update-columns-in-a-table-and-return-whole-table-object)

Comment: As a quick solution, u can just do copy on the cat entity with the modified value and return it only if the operation is successful.

Comment: I don't think copying the input will work for fields that are updated via trigger (lastUpdated timestamp etc). which is very common for Postgresql databases.

Answer (score 5):

You should try the following:

```
def update(id: Long, cat: Cat): Future[Option[Cat]] = db.run {
  cats.filter(_.id === id).update(cat).map {
    case 0 => None
    case _ => Some(cat)
  }
}
```

You should return a `Future[Option[Cat]]` instead of a `Future[Cat]`, because the cat with provided ID might not exist (the `update` method returns `0` value then). Violating integrity constraints will result in a `Failure` of the `Future`.

Comment: I think this may work in this specific case but -- 1. Does the update really "fail" if there is no user with this ID? Probably not, in fact this is what your "updatesCount" 0 case covers. 2. I don't think this sequence of DB operations results in a lock, so even though you're running in a transaction you might as well not be... this is pretty much an update followed by a select wrapped in a meaningless transaction. Correct me if I'm wrong but I had similar misconceptions about transactions. They provide rollback for failures but I think this Q is more about atomic update/read.

Comment: I have simplified my solution in a way that makes no use of transactions, however the earlier solution would still work as expected. Answering your questions:
1. You're right - the word `fail` was a bit misleading in my post, because that case wouldn't return a `Failure` (however it could if you'd replace `DBIO.successful` with `DBIO.failed`).
2. Since it was an update followed by a selection, that transaction wasn't meaningless (the whole thing is ACID now). From the docs: `the transaction is committed if the wrapped Action succeeds, or rolled back if the wrapped Action fails`.

Comment: cool. i get what you're saying my point was simply that nothing in that update/select sequence would have caused a transaction rollback. Even if you threw a failure in your case of 0 affected rows what are you really doing, rolling back an update of nothing? I believe there is no guarantee against race conditions within the transaction (you can update & select and what you're selecting may have already been changed by another thread), only simply that each line will be executed individually and rolled back in case of any failure. In some cases getting the exact state matters, others it may not