# Returning for update and delete queries in Slick

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick

I am trying to adapt the ingenious solution from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30212785/slick-3-0-update-columns-in-a-table-and-return-whole-table-object/52583742#52583742) to work with arbitrary update and delete queries in Postgres. It works well when there is only one bind parameter in the resulting query. E.g.:

```
users.filter(_.name === "Ann").map(_.name).updateReturning(users.map(_.name), "Jane")
```

produces working statement

```
update "users" set "name" = ? where "users"."name" = 'Ann' returning "name"
```

However if there is more than one parameter, it fails, e.g. in this query:

```
users.filter(_.created < OffsetDateTime.now).map(_.name).updateReturning(users.map(_.name), "Jane")
```

=>

```
update "users" set "name" = ? where "users"."created" < ? returning "name"
```

where "created" has, for example, `OffsetDateTime` type. I have not figured when exactly Slick puts literal parameter values in the query and when it leaves "?" for JDBC to fill (perhaps when parameter is an object and not a primitive?). So it does not have to be OffsetDateTime, just any other complex type supported by vanilla Slick or slick-pg.

In the posted solution new `slick.sql.SqlStreamingAction` is built using `slick.jdbc.SQLActionBuilder` which accepts single `slick.jdbc.SetParameter[Unit]`. Can somebody explain how it works and how to construct it to accept not just the first query parameter but all parameters that were defined in the original query?